# I need help with this secret santa puzzle

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, word, enigmatic-puzzle

My secret santa is playing a game with me.

One of the games is a series of 6 riddles, that make up a word of 6 letters or a phrase of 6 words that help me decrypt an encrypted message through an app.

1-

> This word is very important for every living creature. No man, woman, animal or plant can survive without having it. But one must be careful, having an excess of it can actually kill you.

2-

> It’s me!

3-

> 56a79676f6c6f6070714

4-

> 64-36-3-9-343-3-2401-8-64-6-2-8-64-36-4

5-

> This word is a number that is so perfect in a way so satisfying for the OCDs

6-

> $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{x^2+7x^7} + x^5}{\sqrt[5]{3x^{17}} + 8 \ln \ln (x^6 - 7x^4 + 3x^2 - 1)} = 25.8$$  Find $x$.

Any help would be highly appreciated:)

Thank you

Comment: by the way, if this puzzle is not original, please state the source clearly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

I have a another suggestion for 1

> Heat / Warmth: Most animals need some form of heat to live (yes some
>  bacteria might be able to remain dormant at very low temps, but you
>  could argue they don't *live*) but obviously too much and we would
>  burn!

p.s. Can't get the hang of this spoiler markup - it's either hidden and jumbled or tidy and not hidden :(

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

1:

> Oxygen: crucial to all living things, can poison you with an excessive intake/ 
> Water(credits @Pugmonkey): crucial to living things, but how can it kill us? Flood? Drowning?
> I believe it's the former since it can be **O**, **OO** (O2) or **8**, atomic number of Oxygen

4:

> Taking it as a regular math expression we get -2923, which apparently isnt the answer

Comment: Don't plants consume Carbon Dioxide and Sunlight and produce Oxygen?

Comment: yes, during photosynthesis. but plants also undergo respiration where oxygen is taken in and carbon dioxide is given out

Comment: This seems more likely to be rot13 (jngre).

Comment: thanks but how can it kill us? Drown/ flood?

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

> I used [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x%5E2%2B7*x7)%5E(1%2F4)%20%2B%20x%5E5)%2F((3*x%5E17)%5E(1%2F5)%2B8*ln(ln(x%5E6-7*x%5E4%2B3*x%5E2-1)))%3D25.8) to solve the equation. The result for x is:
>  x = 8.7955255...